# How to auto-adjust size of other input fields while typing into input field #1?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with an HTML/JavaScript/CSS page that looks something like this,

```
       input field: (base10) [100                  ]
output field #1 (base08) [144                  ]
output field #2 (base19) [55                   ]
output field #3 (base36) [2S                   ]
```

and I am trying to achieve something like this,

```
       input field: (base10) [100                  ]
output field #1 (base08) [144]
output field #2 (base19) [55]
output field #3 (base36) [2S]
```

with real-time adjustment to the "output" field sizes. The brackets denote the field sizes visible on my screen. How to code that?

All 4 of those lines use the HTML input tag with unique id's. In this case I typed "100" into the base10 field which is arbitrarily long in size, and in real time the JavaScript updates multiple output fields with the number 100 written in other counting systems, and that already works fine, no problem there.

The problem is all those output fields are a pre-determined/hard-coded size, whereas their contents are all different sizes. What I need is for the size attribute of the fields called #1, #2, and #3 to be dynamically updated in real time too, so the field snugly fits each of the contents.

Something tells me that the solution will involve things like `onkeyup="Resize(this);"` and `document.getElementsByName` or something similar (preferably no jQuery), but I am not the best with JavaScript syntax and I am just modding this pre-written page under GNU GPL, so I need your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide demo showing before/after. Not entirely clear what objective is

Comment: many jsfiddles already provide that size-update effect, on the focused js input element. my question in a different form perhaps would be, how to update more than 1 js input element simultaneously, or how to document.write some input field value?
have you seen how many js code snippets are free on the www that convert bases in a variety of ways? those are good demo's, there.
and thanks charlie

Comment: still not clear at all what you are wanting. Updating numerous input's isn't difficult. But you still haven't really identified effect needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself with :

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.width = ((document.getElementById("foo").value.length + 1) * 6.5);
```

it's pretty close, not 100%, as far as the style width matching the input element contents, but at least it's dynamic which is what I was looking for.